# What is the Z-transformation of following discrete time signal of this?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, z-transform

I am learning how $Z$-Transforms work, but I have no encountered a situation in which the bound does not account for any signal.

Take for example the following discrete time signal:
\begin{cases}
x(-2)=4\\
x(-1)=0\\
x(0)=2\\
x(1)=4\\
x(2)=6\\
x(3)=8\\
x(4)=-2\\
\end{cases}
I need to find the $Z$-transform for $x(n)=0$ for $n$ from $-\infty$ to $-3$ and also for $n$ from $5$ to $\infty$.

My answer for this would be $0$ for both cases.

Is this correct?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use the [basic tutorial and quick reference guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and also show the work you have done so far.

Comment: Both cases? I see only one case. And the answer is incorrect. Can you explain how you got $0$ for "both cases"? The answer is pretty definitional.

Comment: I am assuming that by "x(n)=0 for n from -infinity to -3 and also for n from 5 to infinity" I am supposed to find two transforms (1) for the case where it is going from -infinity to -3, where it is always 0, and (2) for bounds where it is 5 to infinity, where is is also 0. I might be wrong as I may have interrupted the question incorrectly.

Comment: For finding the $Z$ transform $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}x(n)z^{-n}$ you need the value of a sequence $x(n)~\forall n\in\Bbb Z$. So those two cases are actually the description of the same sequence.

Comment: I see! I think there is where I got confused. If this is the case then I believe the Z-transform should be: 4Z^2+2+4Z^-1+6z^-2+8Z^-3-2Z^-4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For finding the $Z$ transform $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}x(n)z^{-n}$ you need the value of a sequence $x(n)~\forall n\in\Bbb Z$. So those "two cases" are actually the description of the same sequence.

The $Z$-transform is given by $x(-2)z^2+x(-1)z^1+\cdot\cdot\cdot+x(4)z^{-4}=4z^2+2+4/z+6/z^2+8/z^3-2/z^4$ since the remaining $x(i)$'s are all zero.

Comment: Thank you. I was just confused on the sequence actually being one.

Comment: You are welcome! If you are satisfied with my answer consider accepting it by clicking the tick mark button next to it. @hollyjolly.

Comment: Just did! Thanks again.